# Filter data frame by results from tapply function

Tags: r, subset, tapply

I'm trying to apply a tapply function I wrote to filter a dataset.  Here is a sample data frame (df) below to describe what I'm trying to do.

I want to keep in my data frame the rows where the value of df$Cumulative_Time is closest to the value of 14.  It should do this for *each* factor level in df$ID (keep row closest the value 14 for each ID factor).

```
ID  Date    Results TimeDiff    Cumulative_Time
A   7/10/2015   71  0   0
A   8/1/2015    45  20  20
A   8/22/2015   0   18  38
A   9/12/2015   79  17  55
A   10/13/2015  44  26  81
A   11/27/2015  98  37  118
B   7/3/2015    75  0   0
B   7/24/2015   63  18  18
B   8/21/2015   98  24  42
B   9/26/2015   70  30  72
C   8/15/2015   77  0   0
C   9/2/2015    69  15  15
C   9/4/2015    49  2   17
C   9/8/2015    88  2   19
C   9/12/2015   41  4   23
C   9/19/2015   35  6   29
C   10/10/2015  33  18  47
C   10/14/2015  31  3   50
D   7/2/2015    83  0   0
D   7/28/2015   82  22  22
D   8/27/2015   100 26  48
D   9/17/2015   19  17  65
D   10/8/2015   30  18  83
D   12/9/2015   96  51  134
D   1/6/2016    30  20  154
D   2/17/2016   32  36  190
D   3/19/2016   42  27  217
```

I got as far as the following:

```
spec_day = 14  # value I want to compare df$Cumulative_Time to


# applying function to calculate closest value to spec_day
    tapply(df$Cumulative_Time, df$ID, function(x) which(abs(x - spec_day) == min(abs(x - spec_day))))
```

Question: how do I include this tapply function as a means to do the filtering of my data frame df?  Am I approaching this problem the right way, or is there some simpler way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing?  Any help would be appreciated--thanks!

Comment: If you want to stick with R base language, you can have a look at `split(df, df$ID)` then with a `lapply` use your approach to retrieve indexes corresponding to a specific ID `result <- lapply(mysplit, FUN=function(df){df[which()...,]})`. Finally combine all filtered data with a `do.call("rbind", result)`. I would encourage to investigate `data.table` options

Comment: Thanks, @EricLecoutre!  I remember reading about split(), so I will try this method as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it, note that I didn't use `tapply`:

```
spec_day <- 14
new_df <- do.call('rbind', 
            by(df, df$ID, 
            FUN = function(x) x[which.min(abs(x$Cumulative_Time - spec_day)), ]
              ))
new_df

  ID      Date Results TimeDiff Cumulative_Time
A  A  8/1/2015      45       20              20
B  B 7/24/2015      63       18              18
C  C  9/2/2015      69       15              15
D  D 7/28/2015      82       22              22
```

`which.min` (and its sibling `which.max`) is a very useful function.

Comment: Thanks, @bouncyball!  I think I understand which.min--thanks for pointing me to this function as well as introducing me to another approach for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more concise and faster alternative using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(abs(Cumulative_Time - 14))], by = ID]
#   ID      Date Results TimeDiff Cumulative_Time
#1:  A  8/1/2015      45       20              20
#2:  B 7/24/2015      63       18              18
#3:  C  9/2/2015      69       15              15
#4:  D 7/28/2015      82       22              22
```

Comment: Thanks, @mtoto!  I do like the conciseness of this one.  It is also fairly intuitive to understand what the code is doing!